# How to create View with xml layout programmatically inside fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, viewgroup

I have some layout and i need to create many Views to add tham to my gridLayout inside fragment.

I have this now:

```
ArrayList<Tables> tables;
            ArrayList<View> tableList = new ArrayList<>();
            tables = parsedArray.get(0).getTables();
            GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

            for (int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++) {
                tableList.add(getView().findViewById(R.id.table_layout));
                //TextView textView = (TextView) tableList.get(i).findViewById(R.id.table_number);
                //textView.setText(tables.get(i).getTableNumber());
                GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(i / 5);
                GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(i);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
                gridLayout.addView(tableList.get(i), i, params);
            }
        }
```

but its wrong way, so I need to find out how to create new Views and add them to my list, in this state I think im tring to make reference to the same View, couz i have this type of error:

```
Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup
```

Fragment code:

```
public static class tablesFragment extends Fragment {

    private VolleySinglton volleySinglton;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;

    public static tablesFragment getInstance(int position) {
        tablesFragment myTablesFragment = new tablesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        myTablesFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myTablesFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

        volleySinglton = VolleySinglton.returnInstance();
        requestQueue = volleySinglton.getRequestQueue();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        ArrayList<RoomsClass> parsedArray = parseRoomsResponse(response);
                        updateViews(parsedArray);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {

                }
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        return layout;
    }

    private void updateViews(ArrayList<RoomsClass> parsedArray) {

        // Extract relevant data from the array

        if (parsedArray == null || parsedArray.isEmpty()) {
        } else {

            ArrayList<Tables> tables;
            ArrayList<View> tableList = new ArrayList<>();
            tables = parsedArray.get(0).getTables();
            GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.grid_layout);

            for (int i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++) {
                tableList.add(getView().findViewById(R.id.table_layout));
                //TextView textView = (TextView) tableList.get(i).findViewById(R.id.table_number);
                //textView.setText(tables.get(i).getTableNumber());
                GridLayout.Spec row = GridLayout.spec(i / 5);
                GridLayout.Spec col = GridLayout.spec(i);
                GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(row, col);
                gridLayout.addView(tableList.get(i), i, params);
            }
        }

        // Replace the place holders in the relevant views

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public interface VolleyCallback {
        void onSuccess(ArrayList<RoomsClass> result);
    }

    private ArrayList<RoomsClass> parseRoomsResponse(JSONObject response) {

        ArrayList<RoomsClass> roomsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            JSONArray rooms = response.getJSONArray("rooms");

            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentRoom = rooms.getJSONObject(i);
                RoomsClass room = new RoomsClass();
                room.setRoomId(currentRoom.getInt("room_id"));
                room.setRoomLabel(currentRoom.getString("label"));

                JSONArray tables = currentRoom.getJSONArray("tables");
                for (int j = 0; j < tables.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject currentTable = tables.getJSONObject(j);
                    room.addTable(currentTable.getInt("table_id"), currentTable.getInt("table_number"));
                }
                roomsArray.add(room);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return roomsArray;
    }
}
```

there may be some more issues cuz i'm editing it right now.

**I make this chaneges:**

```
View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_layout, gridLayout, false);
                tableList.add(view);
```

and when im trying to add Views the thing go OK.

P.S.
I dont close question yet, couz there mb some troubles.

Comment: show me your all fragment code

Comment: code added to the qestion... and its look bad(

Comment: `findViewById()` inside the for loop is probably returning `null`, which probably means there's no view with that ID in the layout yet. But if it didn't return null, then you'll have a problem if `i` is greater than 1 because it will find the same view each time and try to add that view, but the second add with throw an exception since it's been added already.

Comment: so how do i add a new view not the same all time?